# x64 Portable executable not working

Tags: 64-bit, portable-executable

I created an exact replica of this file in a hex editor: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKwgd.jpg

The problem is, the .exe file I made from it doesn't work, it says it's an invalid Win32 application when trying to run it.  Is there something flawed in it?  I've checked and double checked my file...

I'm not sure where I can host an exe file but I can email it if someone else wants to check it.

I should also mention I'm running Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PE binary file from that illustration is already available [here](http://corkami.googlecode.com/files/pe101-64b.zip) from the author, Ange Albertini. I have tested it both on Windows 7 and Windows 8/8.1, and it runs just fine, so you can use it for comparison with your binary.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone was wondering, the difference between the image and the executable is that there has to be 0's at the end of the file to match the section size.  It doesn't work without that.

Comment: To be a bit more precise (because "section size" may be misunderstood), each section in the file must contain `SizeOfRawData` number of bytes, as specified in the [`IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680341(v=vs.85).aspx), and must be zero-padded up to the next `FileAlignment` boundary (given in the [`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx)) before the next section or the end of the file. Each section, and also the file itself, is thus a multiple of the file alignment.